# .NET MAUI and gRPC service with JSON Transcoding

Tags: rest, grpc, maui, .net-8.0

I have developed a .NET MAUI app that communicates directly with the backend service using a gRPC service. For this, the MAUI app holds a reference to the proto file which is used by the backend gRPC service as well.

We can also use JSON Transcoding with gRPC. In this way, we do not need to have a reference of the proto file that the gRPC server application uses. The JSON transcoding will deserialize the JSON request message to the protobuf message directly. In the browser based app, we are going to use JSON transcoding with gRPC.

My question is - Is there any performance overhead associated with JSON transcoding as it involves serialization/deserialization process in order to convert to/from protobuf messages?

If the performance overhead is negligible then we can use JSON transcoding with .NET MAUI app as well. Kindly advise

Comment: There should be an overhead at least because protobuf marshaling/unmarshaling is faster than JSON. But I couldn't find any benchmarks for .net json transcoding. Maybe worth benchmarking this in your own environment.

Comment: JSON Transcoding isn't gRPC at all. It's an HTTP response with messages sent as JSON. The overhead is the same as any other HTTP API response. There's no client streaming and server streaming essentially leaves the HTTP connection open, writing one message per line. There are no `protobuf messages` involved

Comment: If you don't want the binary protobuf protocol and known schema provided by `proto` definitions, why use gRPC at all?